# ng-repeat not displaying the individual items

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

When running the code below in my angular 1.x app I can see the first line returns the following :

`[ { "id": 121, "valid": true }, { "id": 123431, "valid": false } ]`

However when I try to display the `valid` or `id` property in the ng-repeat  on the following line I see nothing whatsoever? What am i doing wrong??

```
{{ allItems | json }}
<div ng-repeat="item in allItems">
 {{ item.valid }}
</div>
```

Comment: not sure that true and false are stringified. Try `{{ item.valid ? "true" : "false" }}`. To debug you could use `<pre>{{ item | json }}</pre>` inside your ng-repeat item, then `<pre>{{ item.valid | json }}</pre>`

Comment: Good call - I have done that and can see the array only loops though once (not twice as expected??)

Comment: replace `{{ allItems | json }}` by `<pre>{{ allItems | json }}</pre>` and `ng-repeat="item in allItems"` by `ng-repeat="item in allItems track by $index"`. Are you sure the 'allItems' is a json and not a stringified string ? You will see it directly with the <pre> trick

Comment: @Zabs Show me how in https://plnkr.co/edit/4k57QFTHkrbReCdeCSUy?p=preview . It seems to be working fine